# Effect like "delete event" animation uitableview

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, animation, uikit

I'm trying to recreate animations like 'delete event' button animation. Like on this picture

[image]

How can I do this?

At least some ideas?

Comment: I'm trying to animate UIButton like as animation on this pic(while swipe) http://i.stack.imgur.com/2vdxd.png

Comment: But what have you tried? What attempts have you made already? Where are you tripping up?

Comment: I don't know how. I tried to change the frame width, but it's not cut off button. Like `[UIView animateWithDuration:0.1 animations:^{ button.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,1,35); }];` But you understand that this isn't the solution

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution off the top of my head would be to place your custom button in a plain container view (i.e. `UIView` with transparent background) and animate the frame of the container view as needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can place the button inside a UIView with ClipSubviews = YES. Then animate the frame of that container view instead of the one of the button.